# Change the application id without affecting the push notification with parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Update: I have solve the problem by myself. The problem was I have forgotten to write the push service and the GcmBroadcastReceiver in the manifest. I might have remove them by accident. Beside this, it will be interesting if someone can confirm that by changing the application id, the push notification with parse will still work.

I have an application configured to received the push notification with Parse. Now I would like to have another flavour of the app using the same push notification. The problem here is seems that by changing the application id is not enough. What I receive when I initilize the app is the follow error:

```
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <permission android:name="com.jiahaoliuliu.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <uses-permission android:name="com.jiahaoliuliu.android.horizontal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746):   <intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746):     <category android:name="com.jiahaoliuliu.android.horizontal" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746):   </intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo( 5746): </receiver>
```

Is there any way to change the application id in the build.gradle file and still have the push notification working with Parse?

Comment: Can you post the code of your manifest file?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The question was solved. I have forgotten the GcmBroadcastReceiver and Push Service in the manifest. Beside that, it will be great to know if by changing the application id the push notification using parse is still working. Can anyone confirm that?